crossreferencing via \label and \ref in pgfgantt?
It does not seem possible to refer via \ref to elements in pgfgantt. Or is there some way to do so?
EDIT: I would be interested to have a similar functionality as the one available in pgfplot with addplot as described here: How to label a TiKz shape for referencing its legend in the caption
For example this would allow to display a small diagram of the milestone diamond in the caption. More broadly it would be useful to be able also to refer to bars so that via the caption I can display a small legend.
Here a MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ganttchart}[
        vgrid ={{draw=none},{dotted,thick}},
        hgrid style/.style=dotted,
        title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
        include title in canvas=false,
        y unit chart=0.4cm,
        title height=1,
        ]{1}{25}
\gantttitle{Year 1}{12} \gantttitle{Year 2}{12} \\
\ganttgroup{WP 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{C1}{1}{2}\\
\ganttbar{C2}{1}{2}\\
\ganttmilestone[inline]{M1}{7}\label{M3} 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is the milestone \ref{M3}.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


That is not an MWE ;). Please make it compilable. I don't know pgfgantt, but the answer is probably 'No'. Because there is no out-of-the-box system in PGF for this, so unless a package author specifically designs a framework for it, it isn't available. (I also think it is weird to call what you describe a \ref! I expected a system which let you label and refer to things, as in the main document. What you describe sounds more like thumbnails.)

Fixed. I was indeed referring to have a small thumbnail for the milestone. This is a feature I have found in pgfplots and works pretty well.
More broadly how can I make a legend of the symbols used my gantt diagram? I was planning to have various shapes for different types of milestones and indicate these to the reader in the caption. As an example, since this is an academic project, I would like to indicated both in diagram and via a thumbnail in the caption a conference submission say with the standard diamond shape and via a square a journal submission.

I wonder if egreg's answer would work if you used symbols rather than text. That wouldn't give you thumbnails, but it would certainly allow things like diamonds and squares.

At the end I have gone for solution where I mimic the shapes of interest using tikz shapes library. Here a MWE for anybody that may be interested
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum \tikz \node[shape=diamond,fill=black,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1em] {}; lorem ipsum   (\tikz \node[shape=star, draw, star points=6, star point ratio=1.65,  inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 1em]{};) lorem ipsum (\tikz[baseline] \draw[line width=3pt] (0,0.5ex) -- (0.5cm,0.5ex);)  lorem ipsum.


\begin{ganttchart}[Mile2/.style={milestone/.append style={fill=blue,shape=star}}]{1}{5}
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={pattern=north west lines}]{Some bar}{1}{2}
  \ganttmilestone[inline]{}{2}\\
  \ganttbar{Another bar}{1}{3}\ganttmilestone[inline,Mile2]{}{3}\\
\end{ganttchart}


\end{document}

